# How do I dynamically create channels and associate data using agora.io

Tags: javascript, json, agora.io

I am new to one-to-many live video streaming and have successfully integrated the agora.io Web SDK v3.1.1 sample provided and I need to finish integration by dynamically creating channels/new projects.

For example:
When user[a] signs up for an account on mywebsite.com, agora.io API creates a channel with the username that will come from user[a] account, and then produce a response containing (appid, token, channel) relevant information.

When user[a] logs into mywebsite.com, their agora.io API (appid, token, channel) relevant information automatically populate:

```
var appID = 'user[a]app1D';
var Token = 'user[a]t0k3n';
var channel = 'user[a]channel';
```

Please, I am a total novice to this, please help, it took a couple months to figure out the gradual improvement in general web livestreaming procedures and which codes work best and agora made integration very very easy to implement. I'm a bit pressed for time now that my site is almost complete. I'm really stuck on these points above - Your help is much appreciated.

Or maybe I should hire for the work, which I am willing. Please advise.

Comment: Is there a strict requirement fro your side to create multiple projects? Why are your users trying to create a new appid just to use your platform? i.e Are you a reseller of Agora or are you trying to use Agora in your platform?

Comment: @vineeth srrini: thanks i installed agora in my platform. I actuall solved my issue the next day, and thought i marked this question solved but it seems not to have been done properly. I will close this question + thanks!